# Success Factors Status update of an Job Application

Tags: sap-successfactors

As per the ODATA API document of Success Factors we can update the job application status. But when tried using the /upsert API, I am getting failure that the status field cannot be updated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tugNd.png)

Comment: would be glad the get an response to my answer, at least if it helped or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Endpoint** (depending on your data center):

```
https://api12preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/upsert?$format=json
```

**Type/Header:**

```
Type: POST
Header: 
   Content-Type = application/json
   Authorization = your Type of Authorization Token (Basic/OAuth)
```

**Body (Type application/json):**

```
{ "__metadata": { "uri": "JobApplication(<YOUR_APPLICATION_ID>)" },
"appStatusSetItemId" : "<targetStatus>"
}
```

Example from (Default-status (86) to pre-screening status (90))

```
{ "__metadata": { "uri": "JobApplication(141)" },
"appStatusSetItemId" : "90"
}
```

**Permissions required:**

```
Recruiting Permissions -> OData Application Create (sometime necessary for update!)
Recruiting Permissions -> OData Application Update
```

**Further Information:**

```
1) in the body request you are posting (see above) you also need to provide all 
   required fields defined in your job application, otherwise update won't work

2) You can see your instance's appStatusSetItemId in "Edit Applicant Status Configuration". 
   It is the internal status from the pipeline of your applications.
```